# Can't find Wordpress missplaced CSS location

Tags: php, wordpress

There is some code showing raw CSS at the footer of a Wordpress site.
I have been looking for it all over the database using the CLI. However it is not showing or I'm not making good searches.

Any idea of where could it be placed so I can remove it? Seems like a filter issue but I'm not proficient with Wordrpress. This span.onsale selector is the problematic one:

```
...
</script>
span.onsale {
width: 100px;
height: auto;
}
<script>
...
```

Comment: could be generated by javascript or in-between a conditional statement (more likely). Either from a plugins or from the theme itself. Try to disable all plugins to know where to look. look if it's only on specific pages or on every pages. If you can't find it and you still want to remove it, we can do a regex.

Comment: Thanks! I have find it. It is a theme (divi) issue. I tried to regex it but when i replace the string the page gives a critical. I will find a way to handle it now that I know where is the problem.